# Are there any instances of a Jedi using the Force on themself?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

The Force can be used for moving objects, including living animals.  There are a few instances I can think of where the Force is used on a person, such as Anakin using the Force in Season 1, Episode 4 of The Clone Wars on Padme when she has to jump between trains.  Has there ever been a situation, in TV shows, comics, or the EU, where a Jedi has used the Force on their own body, such as propelling themself up a ledge or almost flying?  I am excluding cases such as jumping higher than normal; I am thinking of more outright examples.

Comment: Force jumping? That’s used in every single movie I believe...

Comment: Why downvote this question? It's no better or worse than the linked duplicate, and the keywords for one would not necessarily bring up the other.

Comment: @Adamant I downvoted before the dupe mainly because the answer is obvious per my first comment. Watching any one movie would give you the answer.